# Java Spring requestMatchers permit paths within authenticated path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to protect all paths at /admin/** but allow /admin/auth/** for the login.

I have tried this  but does not work;

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );
        // Disable csrf for now
        http.csrf(c -> c.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).ignoringRequestMatchers("admin/**"));
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The fine-grained request pattern** should be applied **first**.

with the broader scope pattern filtered out first if it's above it

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            );
    // Disable csrf for now
    http.csrf(c -> c.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).ignoringRequestMatchers("admin/**"));
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Strange I tried that before but it did not work. I just tried it again and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I might do it using regular expressions. It is not really necessary if you have not done it. I tried to search online but I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `authorizeRequests` method?
The order of matching patterns is essential. First, you should specify the more specific way (`/admin/auth/`) and allow access to it with `permitAll()`. Then, select the more general pattern (`/admin/`) and require authentication for it with `authenticated()`.

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests
        .antMatchers("/admin/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
    )
    .csrf(c -> c
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .ignoringAntMatchers("/admin/**")
    )
    .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

return http.build();
```